# Synchronize two plots from different datasets based on time in R

Tags: r, plot, signals, signal-processing

I have two signals with different frequencies which do not have the same duration. I would like to plot them in the same plot and the X axis would correspond to the signal with the longest duration.

Let me explain. This is the 100Hz signal with large duration.

[image: This is the 100Hz signal with large duration]

And this is the the 1Hz signal with the shorter duration.
[image]

You can see that the first signal lasts from 29:00 to 42:00 while the second one lasts from 29:00 to 35:00.

I would like to create plot that will ideally be like the one that is shown below:
[image: The solution to my problem!]

I have tried to use `merge` command in R but since the time column is not exactly the same (due to differences in milliseconds) I don't get the whole sample.
This is the code I use:

```
merged_signal <- merge(signal100, signal1, by="time")
```

Comment: Try to set xlim, something like: `plot(firstData, xlim = c(29, 42), col = "blue"); lines(secondData, col = "red")`

Comment: Please provide example data, and your code for plotting. It will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @zx8754 your answer to your comment was very helpful and solved my question.